# Doxygen manner of presentation member variables

Tags: c++, doxygen

How to change in doxygen on graphs this:
[image]

to include member variables in second empty field?

Edit:

Inheritance graph is ok, only colaboration is problem

Doxygen version : 1.8.17

Doxyfile:

```
    # Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NUMBER         = Beta
PROJECT_BRIEF          = Game
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_USED_FILES        = NO
INPUT                  = /home/adrian/Dokumenty/eclipse/0_FULL_GAME/headers
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 50
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES
```

It happens for probably every code, for example this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    float number;
    string string;
public:
    float getNumber();
};
```

Comment: Doxygen version? Settings in your doxygen settings file? Code from which it is generated?

Comment: I don't see `HAVE_DOT` in your Doxyfile. Do you have the Graphviz dot tool installed and available in your `PATH`?

Comment: I installed doxygen via apt. I have HAVE_DOT set to YES, this file print only fields that differ from default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I had to set `HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS` to `YES`.

FRom the documentation:

> HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS
>
> If set to YES the inheritance and collaboration graphs will hide inheritance and usage relations if the target is undocumented or is not a class.
>
> The default value is: YES.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [the `UML_LOOK` tag](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_uml_look) is set to `YES`:

> **`UML_LOOK`**
>
> If the `UML_LOOK` tag is set to `YES`, doxygen will generate
> inheritance and collaboration diagrams in a style similar to the OMG's
> Unified Modeling Language.
>
> The default value is: `NO`.
>
> This tag requires that the tag `HAVE_DOT` is set to YES.
>
> **`UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS`**
>
> If the UML_LOOK tag is enabled, **the fields and methods are shown
> inside the class node.** [...]

Also make sure (as stated in the requirements for `UML_LOOK` above) that you need to set [the `HAVE_DOT` tag](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_have_dot) to `YES` (and naturally have the dot tool available from the path).

> **`HAVE_DOT`**
>
> If you set the `HAVE_DOT` tag to `YES` then **doxygen will assume the
> dot tool is available from the path. This tool is part of Graphviz**,
> a graph visualization toolkit from AT&T and Lucent Bell Labs. The
> other options in this section have no effect if this option is set to
> `NO`
>
> The default value is: `NO`.

Comment: Also see what happens when you set `HAVE_DOT=YES` (requires you installed graphviz dot)

Comment: I have `UML_LOOK` set to `YES` and `HAVE_DOT` to `YES`. It look like the inheritance graph is ok, but this problem occur only on colaboration graph

Comment: See my comment with the question so we can see what you are missing (you can also indicate that in an image).

Comment: I added some info, I'm trying to add settings, but it is from doxywizard and there is a loot of comments so please wait a while

Comment: You will have a Doxyfile. Just run in a command window `doxygen -x` on this file and you have the small set.